# Where to find the source code of built-in map() function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I jump to definition of map() function in PyCharm, I get a code with only pass-construction in it and no code which makes something. I tried to find it in other places, but it seems like I don't have any idea of where it can be. Please, help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Builtin functions are not written in Python, but rather in C. What you see in you IDE is only a placeholder, it is of course not the real implementation.

Here you can find the [cPython implementation of `map`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3af4b585527743e455145d294049c46b7c823ed9/Python/bltinmodule.c#L1194).

You will notice that since `map` is a class, its method are defined beforehand. By exemple, if you are interested in `map.__next__`, you look for the definition. `map_next`. After those method definitions, you can find the [allocation of  the `map` type](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3af4b585527743e455145d294049c46b7c823ed9/Python/bltinmodule.c#L1329).